# Combining multiple ISOStrings in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object consisting of 3 keys, which represent ISOStrings. I want to combine the date from "date" and the time from "startTime" and "endTime".

```
{
date: "2019-05-16T22:00:00.000Z",
startTime: "1899-12-30T05:00:00.000Z",
endTime: "1899-12-30T21:00:00.000Z",
}
```

I basically want to end up with two ISOStrings (in pseudocode):

- startDate: date + startTime
- EndDate: date + endTime

How would i go about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using simple string parsing, since the ISO is a known format this will always work:

```js
const dates = {
  date: "2019-05-16T22:00:00.000Z",
  startTime: "1899-12-30T05:00:00.000Z",
  endTime: "1899-12-30T21:00:00.000Z",
}
console.log(dates.date.substring(0, 10) + dates.startTime.substring(10));
console.log(dates.date.substring(0, 10) + dates.endTime.substring(10));
```